# I want to protect my flash file 'swf' from copying using C#

Tags: c#, flash

I want to protect my flash file 'swf' from copying using C#.
could you help me ?

Regards.

Comment: Protect it how?  From copying what?  Why using C#?  Your question doesn't make any sense.  Please elaborate.

Comment: The question is too vague.

Comment: protected from copying to another computer.

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately, in order to help, we need a lot more information.  Please post code you've tried, errors you've received and any bits that might shed light on EXACTLY what you're trying to do.  If you need help architecting something, you might try [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You should not close question just because your "experts" do not understand it. Maybe you need better experts? Or people with live experience in copyright protection as example by this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a stream hosting to provide data to a player to open your file. Also you will need to adjust your player accordingly. That will give you all protection you need.
Otherwise your file will be downloaded to user computer.

Comment: I like this answer if its correct.  But how do you "adjust your player"?  The player is on the consumer side,  you cant adjust their settings.

Comment: Take a look at type of players used for playing swf. Example amazon video. It uses flash video but you never get complete swf downloaded to your system.

Comment: oh I see, you're just talking web embedded stuff.